# Jaspersoft visualize.js in AWS gives Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of null

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, jasperserver

I just created a cloud space of jaspersoft and try to test visualize.js by loading sample report. But i am getting javascript error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of null" when try to load below code. My jasper instance is 
http://ec2-54-162-0-97.compute-1.amazonaws.com/jasperserver-pro/ which is version 6.3.0. below is my html code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- Provide the URL to visualize.js -->
      <div id="container"></div>
      <!-- Provide a container for the report -->
      <script src="http://ec2-54-162-0-97.compute-1.amazonaws.com/jasperserver-pro/client/visualize.js?logLevel=debug&_opt=true"></script>
      <script>
         visualize({
           auth: {
             name: "superuser",
             password: "superuser"
           }
         }, function(v) {

           //render report from provided resource
           v("#container").report({
             resource: "/public/Samples/Reports/9.CustomerDetailReport",
             error: handleError
           });

           //show error
           function handleError(err) {
             alert(err.message);
           }

         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

The javascript error as follows,

[image]

Kindly assist you help here.

Thank you in advance,
Thusira

Answer (score 0):

Followed the below guide
https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/visualizejs-troubleshooting

the sample html file need to be accessed via http. not like file. I kept it inside tomcat server

Answer (score 0):

In my case solution was to run this .html file on the web server (Apache HTTPD), running it locally will not work and will occur with exactly this error you get.